# Convert IntStream filter function for Java 7

Tags: java

Background: My application will not allow for me to bring in external libraries, though some may be accessible. I am working in Java 7. 
Disclaimer: This is my first Stack question.

My particular project is an effort to take 2 timestamps with just the local date pulled from them, where the first date is a record creation date and the second is a response date, then determine if the dates lay within my working days. I will later find the difference.

I'm already outside my depth by quite a bit, and so I need assistance 'translating' Java 8 code into Java 7.

I've searched some loosely related answers, but I'm struggling to grasp the fundamentals inherent to the concepts.

The primary code

```
        int allDaysBetween = (int) (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(fromDay, toDay) + 1);
        long allWorkingMinutes = IntStream.range(0, allDaysBetween)
                .filter(i -> isWorkingDay(from.plusDays(i)))
                .count() * WORKING_MINUTES_PER_DAY ;
```

The supporting code

```
    private boolean isWorkingDay(final LocalDateTime time) {
        return time.getDayOfWeek().getValue() < DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.getValue();
    }
```

I'm simply in need of a functional equivalent. From my understanding, plusDays would add to my create date the time where my office is closed, so when I get the diff from my response date, I'll have an int with a smaller value.

The practical application is this:

- office closed on 2019-04-05 19:00:00
- record created on 2019-04-06 09:35:00
- office opens on 2019-04-08 06:00:00
- response created on 2019-04-08 07:32:00

Rather than include the weekend time, I want to exclude it so when I find the diff, I end up with the 'correct' number of minutes based on business hours.

Answer (score 4):

The following Java 8+ stream code:

```
long allWorkingMinutes = IntStream.range(0, allDaysBetween)
        .filter(i -> isWorkingDay(from.plusDays(i)))
        .count() * WORKING_MINUTES_PER_DAY ;
```

Is the same as this general code that will work in any Java version:

```
long count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < allDaysBetween; i++)
    if (isWorkingDay(from.plusDays(i)))
        count++;
long allWorkingMinutes = count * WORKING_MINUTES_PER_DAY ;
```

As for the `ChronoUnit`, `LocalDateTime`, and `DayOfWeek` classes, use the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) for Java SE 6 and 7 support.

Answer (score 0):

### ThreeTen Backport

I am suggesting a library even though you said you could not use an external library (why not?), if only for the benefit of other readers. java.time has been backported. So you can use the same date/time types on Java 7. Only the stream operation is not available (there might be a library for something similar, I don’t know). So I am using a classical loop instead.

```
    LocalDateTime fromDay = LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.APRIL, 12, 0, 0);
    LocalDateTime toDay = LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.APRIL, 16, 0, 0);
    int allDaysBetween = 0;
    for (LocalDate d = fromDay.toLocalDate(); ! d.isAfter(toDay.toLocalDate()); d = d.plusDays(1)) {
        if (isWorkingDay(d)) {
            allDaysBetween++;
        }
    }
    long allWorkingMinutes = allDaysBetween * WORKING_MINUTES_PER_DAY;
    System.out.println(allWorkingMinutes);
```

I have added `threetenbp-1.3.6.jar` and `threetenbp-1.3.6-javadoc.jar` to my project (I believe that newer versions exist) and am using the following imports:

```
import org.threeten.bp.DayOfWeek;
import org.threeten.bp.Duration;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.Month;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit;
```

I changed your supporting method, `isWorkingDay`, to take a `LocalDate` argument because I found it convenient, it would work in your version too.

**You may want to challenge the decision?** If that’s a project decision not to use an external library, you may want to challenge that. You may argue that ThreeTen Backport is not really *external* since it’s a backport of core Java functionality. And you will need the library only until one day you move on to Java 8 or later.

### Links

- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.